# Grunt no "qunit" targets found

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Configuring grunt to make automated JS tests with jenkins and qunit, I am actually blocking on this issue.

When I run grunt: 
    Running "qunit_junit" task

> > XML reports will be written to _build/test-reports
> >     No "qunit" targets found.
> >         Warning: Task "qunit" failed. Use --force to continue.

```
Aborted due to warnings.
```

My Gruntfile:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    var gruntConfig = {};

    grunt.initConfig({
    sync: {
        target: {}
    }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['qunit_junit', 'qunit']);
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-qunit-istanbul');
    gruntConfig.qunit = {
    src: ['static/test/index.html'],
        options: {
            coverage: {
        src: ['static/js/**/*.js'],
        instrumentedFiles: 'temp/',
        htmlReport: 'report/coverage',
        coberturaReport: 'report/',
                linesThresholdPct: 20
            }
        }
    };
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-qunit-junit');
    gruntConfig.qunit_junit = {
        options: {
            dest: 'report/'
        }
    };

};
```

I checked and console.log() in the node_modules, the grunt-contrib-qunit is installed and the task is in it so grunt finds the module and the task but seems not to load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just at a glance - you are creating your config, but not doing anything with it.

Change this line

```
grunt.initConfig({
  sync: {
    target: {}
  }
});
```

to this:

```
grunt.initConfig(gruntConfig);
```

You might also want to move that down below all the other stuff you add to gruntConfig.